# Go back to parent node using XmlReader

Tags: c#, .net, xmlreader

I'm looking at [the example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6473542/75500) below, and I wonder, after I'm done reading all the `image` nodes, how do I get back reading the `last_modified_at` node from parent element?
(See my comments in last few lines of code)

```
public class StackOverflow_6473251
{
    public static void Test()
    {
        string xml = @"
           <movies>
             <movie>
               <score>8.582207</score>
               <popularity>3</popularity>
               <translated>true</translated>
               <adult>false</adult>
               <language>en</language>
               <original_name>Transformers</original_name>
               <name>Transformers</name>
               <alternative_name>The Transformers</alternative_name>
               <type>movie</type>
               <id>1858</id>
               <imdb_id>tt0418279</imdb_id>
               <url>http://www.themoviedb.org/movie/1858</url>
               <votes>28</votes>
               <rating>7.2</rating>
               <certification>PG-13</certification>
               <overview>The Earth is caught in the middle of an intergalactic war /overview>
               <released>2007-07-04</released>
               <images>
                    <image type=""poster"" url=""http://hwcdn.themoviedb.org/posters/304/4bc91347017a3c57fe007304/transformers-original.jpg"" size=""original"" id=""4bc91347017a3c57fe007304""/>
                    <image type=""poster"" url=""http://hwcdn.themoviedb.org/posters/304/4bc91347017a3c57fe007304/transformers-mid.jpg"" size=""mid"" id=""4bc91347017a3c57fe007304""/>
                    <image type=""poster"" url=""http://hwcdn.themoviedb.org/posters/304/4bc91347017a3c57fe007304/transformers-cover.jpg"" size=""cover"" id=""4bc91347017a3c57fe007304""/>
                    <image type=""poster"" url=""http://hwcdn.themoviedb.org/posters/304/4bc91347017a3c57fe007304/transformers-thumb.jpg"" size=""thumb"" id=""4bc91347017a3c57fe007304""/>
                    <image type=""backdrop"" url=""http://hwcdn.themoviedb.org/backdrops/2ce/4bc91339017a3c57fe0072ce/transformers-original.jpg"" size=""original"" id=""4bc9133s9017a3c57fe0072ce""/>
                    <image type=""backdrop"" url=""http://hwcdn.themoviedb.org/backdrops/2ce/4bc91339017a3c57fe0072ce/transformers-poster.jpg"" size=""poster"" id=""4bc91339017a3c57fe0072ce""/>
                    <image type=""backdrop"" url=""http://hwcdn.themoviedb.org/backdrops/2ce/4bc91339017a3c57fe0072ce/transformers-thumb.jpg"" size=""thumb"" id=""4bc91339017a3c57fe0072ce""/>
               </images>
             <last_modified_at>2010-04-26 03:26:14</last_modified_at>
       </movie>
     </movies>";
        XmlReader r = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xml));
        r.ReadToFollowing("original_name");
        string title = r.ReadElementContentAsString("original_name", r.NamespaceURI);
        r.ReadToFollowing("images");
        int imageCount = 0;
        if (r.ReadToDescendant("image"))
        {
            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Image {0}", ++imageCount);
                Console.WriteLine("  Type: {0}", r.GetAttribute("type"));
                Console.WriteLine("  URL: {0}", r.GetAttribute("url"));
                Console.WriteLine("  Size: {0}", r.GetAttribute("size"));
                Console.WriteLine("  ID: {0}", r.GetAttribute("id"));
            } while (r.ReadToNextSibling("image"));
        }
        //read last_modified_at
        //reader.Name evaluates to 'images' at execution time
        //reader.NodeType evaluates to 'EndElement' at execution time
    }
}
```

### UPDATE

In a [similar](http://pastebin.com/ZetsSmmL) scenario, I'm trying to achieve the same result successfully accomplished by the answers below unsuccessfully, and fails at the highlighted line (41) by returning false.
The problem is going from the last `abbr` to `intervals`. And here is where I can't see the difference from the example presented above.

**Update**
[Here](http://pastebin.com/Un0B9i1P) is a complete example.

Comment: Why aren't you just deserializing the xml?

Comment: @Aron what do you mean?

Comment: The question drastically changed and should be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As last_modified_at follows the images you can do it as you did it some lines up:

```
r.ReadToFollowing("last_modified_at");
string lastModified = r.ReadElementContentAsString("last_modified_at", r.NamespaceURI);
```

Comment: [Here](http://pastebin.com/ZetsSmmL)'s code that have same example, but fails! on the highlighted line, `reader.Name` evaluates to `ChordType` and `reader.NodeType` is `EndElement`. Why is that?

Comment: @Shimmy Why are you using pastebin? that code should have been your question.

Comment: As I can see it the code should crash at the line `if (reader.Name != "abbreviations")` already because you do not read the `abbreviations` tag before.

Comment: @Shimmy I've tested this answer it absolutely works and they're absolutely correct about where the code crashes. Make a Short Self Contained Correct Example.

Comment: @Fratyx, I don't understand, why should I be reading the `abbreviations` before?

Comment: @weston, you're right. I initially started the question by posting the similar example. Can you notice the difference between the code in my question (which works according to Fratyx's answer), and the code in pastebin that fails?

Comment: @Shimmy At line 23 of your code the reader "stands before" the `abbreviations` tag. First the reader has to read this element (`reader.Read()`) then the `Name` of the reader will be "abbreviations".

Comment: -1 The `Reader` pattern is a forward reading pattern. There is no guarantee that the underlying data structure can be read backwards (NetworkStream for instance).

Comment: @Aron, the structure and order of the elements in the XML file of the pastebin is guaranteed to be the same. After the `abbreviations` element, I need the reader to move to the `intervals`. @Fratyx, the problem is at line 40, the `abbreviations` part is read just fine.

Comment: I'm sorry but after fixing 'my' problem in line 23 I don't get a problem in line 40.

Comment: Ok. [Here](http://pastebin.com/Un0B9i1P)'s a complete reproduction. I've tried replacing the condition on line 59 with: `!reader.Read()`, `reader.Name != "intervals"`, and `!reader.ReadToFollowing("intervals")`, they all evaluate to false.

Comment: Replace lines 54-56 by `while(reader.Name == "abbr") Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("Abbreviation {0} - Category: {1}, Abbr: {2}", ++i, reader.GetAttribute("category"), reader.ReadElementContentAsString()));`  ReadElementContentAsString() moves to the next sibling and ReadToNextSibling does it again so you skip each second entry by your solution.

Comment: Yep. A few tweaks done but this was the catch. Thanks for you effort and patience @Fratyx.

Comment: You're welcome. Just as advice: Use XmlDocument or even better XDocument for reading XML. XmlReader maybe suitable for very large XML documents but the alternatives are much easier to handle.

Comment: I'm using the `XmlReader`, because it saves performance as it's *forward-only*, as [Steve mentions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26291962/75500). I'll have to iterate on a large amount of nodes at program startup and choose to optimize wherever I can. `XDocument`, although way more flexible and convenient, iterates over from the beginning of the node for each query.

Answer (score 2):

You can't.  From the documentation:

"Represents a reader that provides fast, noncached, **forward-only** access to XML data."

You could read from the start again.

Or, since the data is very small, you could use an XmlDocument which allows greater flexibility.

Comment: According to what you say, an XML reader can only read first element, which doesn't seem right. Please see my updated question with another example.

Comment: @Shimmy I didn't say that.

Comment: You said 'you can't'. According to the documentation there has to be a way, I was talking about next upcoming element, the reason I wanted to go up to parent is for the sake of accessing next node. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

In your [pastebin example](http://pastebin.com/ZetsSmmL), instead of `if (reader.Name != "abbreviations")` do:

```
if (!reader.ReadToFollowing("abbreviations"))
```

It fails because you are not on abbreviations tag yet.

The corresponding working code in the question is:

```
r.ReadToFollowing("images");
```

In fact there are no `reader.Name !=` tests.

Comment: But its the if statement at line 39 that evaluates to false, not the `abbreviations`. It's the `intervals`. Please read update in my question.

Comment: For gods sake man, put the code in your question. This is noob stack overflow stuff. You've got 24.4K how?

Comment: I'd delete my question and start it anew. Please vote for its closure.